# PIVOT for "groups" - rows to columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, unpivot

How-to convert rows (for group) into columns.

Here is the source table that have:

**update: added Id and IdGestion columns**

```
Id  IdGestion   PeticionId  Field       Value
48  17          16          Type        1
49  17          16          SubType     1
50  17          16          Units       1
51  18          16          Type        1
52  18          16          SubType     2
53  18          16          Units       2
54  19          16          Type        3
55  19          16          SubType     6
56  19          16          Units       1
```

How-to get the Pivot table (target):

```
RequestId   Type    SubType Units
16          1       1       1
16          1       2       2
16          3       6       1
```

I try using PIVOT, and ROWNumber(), but get data wrong.

```
select g.PeticionId,  Tipo,SubTipo,Unidades from [GestionSaliente] g
inner join (
SELECT PeticionId,  Tipo,SubTipo,Unidades
FROM
    (select  gs.PeticionId, Campo, Valor 
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY gs.IdGestion ORDER BY gsd.Id) as rn
       FROM [GestionSaliente]  gs
        inner join [GestionSalienteDato] gsd
        on gs.Id = gsd.GestionSalienteId --where  PeticionId = 16 
        
    ) AS source
    PIVOT
    (
     MIN(Valor)
     FOR Campo IN (Tipo,SubTipo,Unidades)
    ) as pvt

) a
on a.PeticionId = g.PeticionId
```

UPDATED: It works now, I think

```
select g.PeticionId,  Tipo,SubTipo,Unidades from [GestionSaliente] g
inner join (


SELECT PeticionId,  Tipo,SubTipo,Unidades
FROM
    (select  gs.Id IdGroup, gs.PeticionId, Campo, Valor 
     FROM [GestionSaliente]  gs
     inner join [GestionSalienteDato] gsd on gs.Id = gsd.GestionSalienteId
    ) AS source
    PIVOT
    (
     MIN(Valor)
     FOR Campo IN (Tipo,SubTipo,Unidades, Id, Peticion)
    ) as pvt
where PeticionId = 16
```

***FOR Campo IN (Tipo,SubTipo,Unidades, Id or IdGroup, Peticion)***

Comment: You need an additional column to distinguish the "groups". Other than by making an inference from the ordering and by the repetition of a sequence of 3 values in the "Field" column, there's nothing in the first table to indicate that there actually are three groups, or which rows relate to which group.

Comment: What is the grouping based on?...the combination of each pivoted field, `Type`, `SubType`, and `Units`?

Comment: @J.D. Source: there are 9 rows. Target: 3 rows. Explain: three groups. Each 3 rows in source is 1 row in Target (with columns *Type, SubType, Units*). Finally in target: 3 rows.

Comment: @Steve is it possible create 3 groups for 9 rows. Explain: for each 3 rows, one group ? maybe using rownumber anyway?

Comment: @Kiquenet, how are you forcing the order of the table in the first place? In other words, how are you querying *that* data in *that specific order*? I can see that the order is intended to be meaningful, but there's no way that order could be derived purely from the values on show. You're either ordering on a column that is discarded, you're relying on the coincidental order of a heap, or you're getting the data from a non-SQL context (where ordering is fixed). This is your problem for using `ROW_NUMBER()` - you still have to specify the ordering columns, putting the cart before the horse.

Comment: SQL tables are unordered sets, so how do we know which three rows go together?

Comment: @steve sorry, I can get more ids: **update: added Id and IdGestion columns** Id identity for any row, IdGestion for group

Comment: @Kiquenet, with the IdGestion column added to the source table, if you pivot now, you will get towards the desired target table (with one row per request, per group).

Comment: @Steve how use pivot and rownumber¿, I get 9 rows anyways, I need 3 rows only, 1 rows per group...

Comment: @Kiquenet, you don't need a rownumber. You just select RequestId, GroupId, Field, Value, and then pivot these on the contents of the Field column. You'll get 3 rows, with 5 columns: RequestId, GroupId, Type, Subtype, Units. It won't collapse to 1 row like before, because the GroupId is now present to distinguish.